# How to efficiently perform concurrent computation with coroutines

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to improve my knowledge of coroutines and currently working on following problem:
*Given a random non empty string with a length of 14 characters, what would be the most efficient way to find a string that contains a specific prefix (let's assume prefix length is 5)?*

Most of the solutions I encountered on the internet either a) manually launch async{} 2 or 3 times or b) launch async{} in a loop and then await all of them to complete which won't work for this scenario.

One approach I tried was to launch new coroutines until I get a non null repsonse from the computation function and cancel the scope after, however there's a clear a performance issue that I'm not seeing since this approach can take more than 20s to calculate for a prefix with length 1.

```
...

private val _flow = MutableSharedFlow<String>()

suspend fun invoke(prefix: String) = withContext(dispatcher) { // dispatcher is Dispatchers.Default
        _flow.onEach {
            println("String is=$it")
            this.cancel()
        }.launchIn(this)

        repeat(Int.MAX_VALUE) {
            launch {
                getString(prefix)?.let {
                    _flow.emit(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }

private fun getString(prefix: String): String? {    // or any other cpu intensive task
        val randomString = generateRandomStringAccordingToSpecs() // implemented elsewhere
        if (randomString .startsWith(prefix = "prefix", ignoreCase = true)) {
            return randomString 
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
```

I also tried an approach with a while loop and 4 parallel executions, for which I'm getting better performace results, however awaiting after every X calculations doesn't seem like the most efficient solution to me:

```
    suspend fun invoke(prefix: String) = withContext(dispatcher) {
        var resultString: String? = getString(prefix)
        while (resultString == null) {
            val tasks = listOf(
                async { getString(prefix) },
                async { getString(prefix) },
                async { getString(prefix) },
                async { getString(prefix) }
            )
            resultString = tasks.awaitAll().filterNotNull().firstOrNull()
        }
        println("String is=$resultString")
    }

private fun getString(prefix: String): String? {    // or any other cpu intensive task
        val randomString = generateRandomStringAccordingToSpecs() // implemented elsewhere
        if (randomString .startsWith(prefix = "prefix", ignoreCase = true)) {
            return randomString 
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
```

In the example above I'm using a find suffix problem, but in general, what is the most efficient way to concurrently perform some CPU intensive calculations with coroutines?
Especially for the calculations where we don't know how many times the task must be executed before we get an answer.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the problem statement. The most efficient way to get a 14-character string with a specific 5-character prefix would be to concatenate that prefix with a randomly generated 9-character string one time. I don’t see how parallelism could help with that.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I think they want to generate full random strings until they get one that starts with the specific prefix, and do that as efficiently as possible. I guess it's possible that the ``generateRandomStringAccordingToSpecs()`` function produces strings that aren't actually random, that have a pattern to them, and writing a function to find a valid 9-char suffix to append isn't practical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a job for the `select` function. Assuming your `generateRandomStringAccordingToSpecs()` is a computationally blocking function, you want to have all your CPU cores working on the problem simultaneously and you just want the first valid result, you could build an operator like this:

```
suspend fun <T> getFirstResult(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): T =
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        coroutineScope {
            select {
                repeat(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()) {
                    async { block() }.onAwait {
                        coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
                        it
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It starts as many parallel coroutines as there are CPUs, and once any of them returns a result, it cancels the rest and returns that result.

So you can use this with a coroutine block that uses a while loop indefinitely until a result is returned:

```
suspend fun invoke(prefix: String) = getFirstResult {
    while(isActive) {
        return@getFirstResult getString(prefix) ?: continue
    }
}
```